# Python display two figures containing multiple subplots side by side

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

As stated in the title, it's possible to place two figures in one when using matplotlib.pyplot?

With this code i generate images like this:

```
def plot_output_image(label, clothes):
plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 2))
columns = 5
rows = 2

for i in range(1, columns * rows + 1):
    filename = similar_images['class'].iloc[i - 1] + '/' + str(similar_images['id'].iloc[i - 1]) + '.jpg'
    img = load_img((files.small_images_classes_directory / filename).absolute().as_posix())
    img = img_to_array(img) / 255
    fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, i)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(img)

plt.savefig((files.ROOT / 'similarity-output' / label / ('out_' + clothes)).absolute().as_posix())
plt.close()
```

[image: similar trousers]

How can i place a second figure side by side in such a way that the output become something like this?
[image: similar trousers + template]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complex layout, you can use `GridSpec` or `subplot2grid()` to generage subplots that can span several rows/columns. See [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html?highlight=gridspec) for more info.

For instance, using gridspec you could do:

```
from matplotlib import gridspec
gs00 = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2, width_ratios=[1,2])
gs01 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2,5, subplot_spec=gs00[0,1])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,3))
left_ax = fig.add_subplot(gs00[0,0])
small_axs = [fig.add_subplot(gs01[i,j]) for i in range(2) for j in range(5)]
```

[image]